# Relation between $(q^4;q^4)_\infty$ and $(q;q)^4_\infty$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Is there any relation between $(q^4\ ;q^4)_\infty$ and $(q\ ;q)^4_\infty$ ?

I have established a claim that,
Let, $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of integers then the coefficients of $q^{7n-1}, n\ge 0$ in $$\displaystyle M(q):= \frac{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n q^{n^2}}{(q;q)_\infty^4}$$ is divisible by $7$.

Proof to the claim:

Given, $$\displaystyle M(q):= \frac{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n q^{n^2}}{(q;q)_\infty^4}$$

then,
$$\displaystyle \frac{(q;q)_\infty^3 \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nq^{n^2}}{(q;q)_\infty^7}\equiv \frac{(q;q)_\infty^3 \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nq^{n^2}}{(q^7;q^7)_\infty} \pmod{7}$$

We can see that it is sufficient to examine the coefficient of $q^{7n-1}$ in $$\displaystyle (q;q)_\infty^3 \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n q^{n^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^j(2j+1)q^{j(j+1)\over 2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nq^{n^2}$$
i.e. we have to examine the coefficient of $q^{(7n-1)}$ in
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (-1)^j (2j+1)q^{\frac{j(j+1)}{2} +n^2}$$

Now, we need those terms for which $$\frac{j(j+1)}{2} + n^2 = 7n-1 \\ \implies \frac{j(j+1)}{2} + n^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{7} \\ \implies 4j^2 + 4j = n^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{7} \\ \implies (2j+1)^2 + n^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{7} $$

Now, $(2j+1) \equiv 0,1,2,4 \pmod{7}$ and $n^2 \equiv 0,1,2,4 \pmod{7}$.

So, we must have $(2j+1) \equiv n \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$,

The coefficients of $q^{7n-1}$ in $\displaystyle (q;q)_\infty^3 \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n q^{n^2}$ is $(-1)^j(2j+1)a_n$ and we have $(2j+1)\equiv 0 \pmod{7}$. So, the coefficients of $q^{(7n-1)}$ in $M(q)$ is divisible by $7$.

Now, **using this I have to prove that $P(7n+5) \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$**. How, should I proceed to obtain the required result ?

**The proof I am seeking is similar to the proof in Page 33 of the book "Number Theory in the spirit of Ramanujan"** for  $P(5n+4) \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$

Comment: Why do you expect there to be one?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff In Berndt's Number Theory in the spirit of Ramanujan Page 33. You can find a proof to $P(5n+4) \equiv 0\pmod{5}$. I am working out the proof for $P(7n+5) \equiv 0\pmod{7}$. In doing so, I came across this. Is this relation possible ?

Comment: I cannot parse the equations you wrote. What should be on the right side?

Comment: P(5n+4) congruent 0 modulo 5  and P(7n+5) congruent 0 modulo 7

Comment: OK. Edited those in. There was no zero there. ;)

Comment: If you throw in $q$ and $(q^2;q^2)_\infty$, there is $(q^2;q^2)_\infty^{24} = (q;q)_\infty^8 (q^4;q^4)_\infty^8 \left((q;q)_\infty^8 + 16\,q\,(q^4;q^4)_\infty^8\right)$, but I suppose that that is not what you are after.

Comment: @ccorn I would request you to kindly have a look at the page number 33 of the Book **Number Theory in the Spirit of Ramanujan** by Bruce Berndt. There you will find a proof for $P(5n+4) \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ I am trying to prove for $P(7n+5) \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$ in a similar way

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Kindly take a look now !

Comment: A better way is to look at Ramanujan's original proof. Your own proof technique in the question is based on Ramanujan's approach. See [this post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/06/congruence-properties-of-partitions-part-2.html?m=0).